# natural logarithm in C using for loop

Tags: c, for-loop

I can't understand how the following program creates a natural logarithm (I wonder if it does). I found it on a blog. If it does not create a natural logarithm how would I make one?

```
void main()
{
    int x,i,j;
    float sum=0,power=1;
    printf("enter x for sum upto 7th term: ");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    for(i=1;i<=6;i++) 
    { 
        power=1; 
        for(j=0;j<=i;j++) 
        { 
            power = power * ((x-1.0)/2.0); 
        } 

        sum = (1.0/2) * power + sum; 
    } 
    sum=sum + (float)(x-1.0)/x;
    printf("%f",sum); 
}
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm

Comment: Curious that `x` is an `int` and not floating point.

Answer (score 1):

The program *might* be trying to calculate the natural logarithm, but it has lots of problems.  Corrections below keeping the OP style

The formula for ln(x) when (x > 0.5) follows

> ln(x) = (x-1)/x  +  (1/2)((x-1)/x)^2 + (1/3)((x-1)/x)^3 + ...

```
void main() {
  int i, j;
  float sum = 0.0f;
  float power;
  float x;
  printf("enter x for sum up to 7th term: ");
  scanf("%f", &x);  // let x be a float rather than limited to int
  for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++) { // do all 7 terms here
    power = 1.0f;
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      power = power * ((x - 1.0f) / x); // need to /x not 2.0
    }
    sum += (1.0f / i) * power; // need to /i not 2.0
  }
  //sum = sum + (float) (x - 1.0f) / x;  not needed as done in above 1st iteration
  printf("ln(%f) = \n%f\n%lf\n", x, sum, log(x));
}
```

---

"Taylor Series Centered at 1" in the below link appears wrong as I suspect its terms should have alternating signs.
http://math2.org/math/expansion/log.htm

Comment: I removed my answer with the wrong link, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Note: A number of optimization improvements are possible for the above code.  But that is getting off topic.